# How to give Username and password when calling HTTP page?

Tags: oracle, model-view-controller, authentication, plsql, oracle11g

I have this code when i run this I get credentials error. How to give credentials .The authentication is set to windows in the https page. Means pop up will appear to get the credentials

```
declare
      req    UTL_HTTP.REQ;
      resp   UTL_HTTP.RESP;
      value  varchar2(1024);
      p_url  varchar2(4000);
      OPT    varchar2(1000);
    BEGIN
      dbms_output.put_line('');
      p_url:='http://www.xyz.com/';

      dbms_output.put_line(p_url);
      req := UTL_HTTP.begin_REQUEST(p_url);
      utl_http.set_header(req, 'User-Agent', 'Mozilla/4.0');

      resp := utl_http.get_response(req);
      loop
         utl_http.read_line(resp, value, true);
         dbms_output.put_line(value);
      end loop;

    exception
        when utl_http.end_of_body then
           utl_http.end_response(resp);
    END;
```

When i run this i get

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
<title>401 - Unauthorized: Access is denied due to invalid credentials.</title>
<style type="text/css">
```

Answer (score 3):

You've got two options (assuming the remote server accepts HTTP basic authentication):

1. you can prepend the url with username:password@url(e.g. 
   `p_url:='http://username:password@www.xyz.com/';`)
2. or you can use the Authorization header. (e.g. 
   `utl_http.set_header(req, 'Authorization', 'Basic ' || utl_encode.base64_encode('username:password'));`)

Comment: The second  option has not worked on my Oracle 12g db. I had to pass 
utl_http.set_header(req, 'Authorization', 'Basic ' ||utl_raw.cast_to_varchar2(utl_encode.base64_encode(utl_i18n.string_to_raw('user:pwd', 'AL32UTF8'))));

utl_encode.base64_encode accepts only a RAW parameter, not a varchar2.

Comment: In 19c you can also use UTL_ENCODE.TEXT_ENCODE, with "encoding" parameter = UTL_ENCODE.BASE84.